# Passing the value of a checkbox

Tags: html, jsp, checkbox

I want to pass the value of a checkbox through then use the value of that as a where clause in a mysql query in my jsp can I give the checkbox a value like this?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="unit" autocomplete="off" value="Networks">
```

Then use the value of that as a where clause like so

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE table_name.field_name = ${param.unit}
```

I want it so param.unit is equal to Networks when its passed

Comment: What is the problem? Also Be careful of [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: @mplungjan its an intranet site, this should not be an issue as far as im aware

Comment: You mean safe to even disgruntled employees who load your form with ""; drop all tables - before they leave

Comment: @mplungjan its a none technical work force as far as databases and programming is concerned.

Comment: Still dont see your point @mplungjan if they break their own intranet site which they wont they will be the ones that suffer not me. They rely on this site everyday

Comment: So you have never seen a fired employee escorted off the premises so he did not break something on purpose?

Comment: No I haven't actually... Lets leave it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the way i did it works anyway give it a value pass it then check it.

Answer (score 0):

To get after page submit use

```
String[] SelectedValues = request.getParameterValues("unit");
```

which returs the array of values checked inthe group unit.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I've managed to make it work the way i tried to do it.